# Number of descendants the person has in a particular generation

Tags: scala, recursion, collections

I am looking a way to calculate number of descendants the person has in a particular generation, but don't know how to do that with scala.

I have a class called "Person" and there are a Vector[Person] to contain children. So family tree is like this:

```
X:Harald
|----X:Mike
|------X:Doe
|------X:Evelyn
|------X:Emilia
|--------X:Mark
|----------X:Rafael
|----X:Don
|------X:Henry
|------X:Milla


class Person(val name: String, val children: Vector[Person]) {

    // number of all Descendants
    def count(list:Vector[Person]):Int={
        var s= 0
          for(child <- list)
          {
             s += 1
             s += count(child.children)
          }
        s
    }


    // Returns the number of descendants the person has in a particular generation.
    def numberOfDescendantsAt(generation: Int): Int = {

        var descendants = 0

        ...

        descendants  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the hard part of the work done in `count`--you just need to keep track of how many times it calls itself, and only increment the count when you're at the right level.